# Doing curl from terminal nothing happen

Tags: curl, ubuntu-14.04

I want to do a simple curl command. When i execute that curl command from my local machine (laptop) i get the following:

[image: curl from local machine]

However, if i SSH into my webserver (VM instance) i am stuck with this:

[image: curl after SSH into my webserver]

It is literally spitting nothing. It just stuck there forever. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

EDIT #1:

So tried to ping google.com, to see if it is reachable

[image: Google is reachable]

Comment: did you check if your vm allows outgoing port 80 connections?

Comment: I'd also guess some routing problem.

Comment: Do you get any response if you run `ping google.com`?

Comment: @seane ping google.com doing just fine

Comment: @MarcB i checked that, i am doing any:any from my internal to outgoing

Comment: Do you see any change if you run `curl http://www.google.com/`?

Comment: @seane using curl -v http://www.google.com i get Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache. And doing curl -V, turns out my curl version is 7.35-xx According to this guy here i need to downgrade to 7.33-03. I will try this first and post the result

Comment: Btw, another temporary solution is: curl -s -S -I -H "Host: example.com" --resolve example.com:80:1.1.1.1 --verbose http://example.com/ (dont forget to replace 1.1.1.1 with the target IP Address)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution. The problem was i am trying to curl from within my own webserver.

For instance, let's say my website is www.example.com and it is being hosted on Server A (IP Address 123.456.789.100). The reason why it spits out "Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache" was because somehow my machine confuse itself. The server machine has an Private IP (because it is VM), Public IP and its FQDN.

Once i properly set this up, i can curl as normal. I hope i am explaining this correctly.

Thanks everyone for all the hints.